# JNI signatures for nested classes?

Tags: class, nested, java-native-interface, signature

I'm trying to use JNI on WindowsXP, java version:

java version "1.6.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

When trying to get jclass for a nested class

jclass c = env->FindClass ("A$B");
assert (c);

the second line asserts, The same thing works ok on Linux with slightly different version of Java (1.5... IIRC).

I've tried several permutations like

LA$B;
A.B
LA.B;

but to no avail.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

OK, I had a similar experience on Native Android, `env->FindClass()` would not find a nested class with `A$B` syntax. I moved stuff around and it wouldn't find even a non-nested class.

What turned out to be the issue is that Java->C++ JNI call **can** find classes, but if you have pure C++ thread, with `jvm->GetEnv / jvm->AttachCurrentThread`, this thread can do JNI stuff but not `FindClass` for some reason.

So my suggestion is if you hit weird `FindClass` behavior on Android, try to move it to a Java stack (i.e Java calling native method), it might help. Note that you might need `NewGlobalRef` for the `jclass` esp if it would be used later from another thread.

P.S. `A$B` is the correct way to refer to nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was resolved in [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5379144).

**Update:** Oracle moved the the forums, the new location is [Signature for nested class?](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6465881)

Here's how the issue was resolved:

> Ok, I've finally found the problem. The nested class is compiled into a separate java class object (A$B.class) - a bit unexpecte for C/C++ programmer. I haven't packeged the file thus the class was reported as 'not found'. Interesting it worked on Linux though. Thanks for your help!

Another hint from me: In case `FindClass` returns null don't just `assert` and guess.  At the very least call `env->ExceptionDescribe()` to get a stacktrace on `stderr`.  Better still, use `env->ExceptionOccurred()` to check for the Java exception being thrown, just like you would on any other Java method you call.

Comment: Link is now dead. (Thanks so much Oracle!)  Can you summarize what it was?